# How can I choose soname of shared library?

Tags: shared-libraries, automake

I am working with 2 shared libraries. The one(foo) is using CMake, the other(bar) is using automake. I eliminated version and soversion property of foo, because some distribution problem about symbolic link, and the result is only libfoo.so(there's no symbolic links).
The problem is that libbar.so requires libfoo.so.1(I found it with readelf). How can I make libbar.so to use libfoo.so, instead of libfoo.so.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make `libbar.so` to use `libfoo.so`, instead of `libfoo.so.1`

The `DT_NEEDED` tag in `libbar.so` is recorded at the time when `libbar.so` is linked, from the set of `DT_SONAME`s of all the libraries it is linked against.

That is, if `libbar.so` has `DT_NEEDED` of `libfoo.so.1`, then it *must* be true that it was linked against `libfoo.so` with `DT_SONAME` of `libfoo.so.1`.

If you have `libfoo.so` *without* `DT_SONAME` (or with `DT_SONAME` of `libfoo.so`), then relinking `libbar.so` against *that* version of `libfoo.so` is necessary and sufficient to get rid of `libfoo.so.1` `DT_NEEDED` tag.